# How to detect if the User is looking at my app (Android)

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to check to see if the user is looking at my app when it receives a c2dm message.  If the user is looking at it then there is no need to generate a notification, otherwise I will generate a notification.  This seems to me like it would be quite trivial. However I have had a tough time trying to find a solution.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
if (yourActivity.getComponentName() == activityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity) {
  // Activity is currently running

}
```

That's one way. Although I would probably use my activity's `onStart()` and `onStop()` to save a reference. There may be simpler ways too.

Comment: No problem. Best of luck with your app.

Comment: Note that this requires the GET_TASKS permission.

Comment: Thanks, yea I had to add android.permission.GET_TASKS to my manifest.

Comment: @JimBlackler the documentation is clear that getRunningTasks "should never be used for core logic in an application". http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int)

Answer (score 1):

> If the user is looking at it then there is no need to generate a notification, otherwise I will generate a notification.

Have your C2DM receiver send an ordered broadcast. Have your activity (or activities) register a high-priority receiver for your broadcast, where they update themselves and abort the broadcast. Have a low-priority receiver for the broadcast registered in the manifest -- if it gets control, have it raise the `Notification`.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is some flag set in onResume() which the notification checks... and then clear the flag onDestroy or onPause